# direct access to visio shape does not work

Tags: vba, visio

I have a question regarding accessing a shape in visio 2003

```
...
dim ovp as visio.page
dim ovs as visio.shape
...
set ovs = ovp.shapes("#shapename#")
...do something with the shape
```

This sometimes does not work!

It gives an error like `shape not found` or similar

```
...
dim ovp as visio.page
dim ovs as visio.shape
...
for each ovs in ovp.shapes

   if ovs.name = "#shapename#" then
   ...do something with the shape

   end if

next
```

This always works. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

When you do `set ovs = ovp.shapes("#shapename#")`, VBA is looking for an exact match for the shape name, in a case-sensitive manner.

When you do `if ovs.name = "#shapename#"` *and* if you have `Option Compare Text` defined in your module, then it will do a case-insensitive comparison.

So, in that particular situation, you may get the results you describe if *both* of the following are true:

1. You have declared `Option Compare Text`
2. You have a mismatch in the case of the shape name you're searching for. E.g the shape is named `"#ShapeName#"` but you are searching for `"#shapename#"`.

Can you comment to clarify if any of this might apply?

Comment: I have no access to visio for the next days but this is very probably the reason

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting #shapename# from?
As a test, inside the foreach ovs, put a debug.print ovs.name to see what names you are dealing with in that collection.